# Google Cloud Printers doesn't show after registering "online account" at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, google, online-accounts

I've added by Google Account to Online Account and enabled everything (calendar, contacts, printers), but printers I've already have registered there (and which I regularly print as a Google Cloud printers from another devices - my cell phone, other computers) doesn't show up at Ubuntu printer settings, or when I try to print issuing b default PDF printer, or other applications.

Do you have any ideas of what's happening? Any log I could inspect to see what the problem is?

Comment: I wonder if this is the solution to your problem: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-a-linux-machine-to-google-cloud-print/ and there is another way that is very similar https://medium.com/the-sysadmin/google-cloud-print-on-ubuntu-16-04-in-10-minutes-1f0bf97ba9d3 but one seems to have to do one or the other to get the connection

Comment: Tks for answering. As long as I understood, the articles you sent refers to a scenario something like PRINTER <-> PRINT SERVER (COMPUTER) <-> GOOGLE CLOUD <-> OTHER DEVICES, which requires a dedicate computer to work. I was looking for something simpler, since it's a Google Cloud prepared printer, already put on cloud, which we can print using Android phones (without installing drivers). It seems to me that Ubuntu 18.04 Online Accounts servers to this last scenario (PRINTER <-> GOOGLE CLOUD <-> DEVICES), and that was why I'm trying to use it.